# Python for x loop returns more then once

Tags: python, subprocess

Very much green here and just writing snippets of code to learn python

I put together the following to look at processing command returns

test.py

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('date', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.read()
for x in output:
        print output
```

I run this, it iterates 58 times:

```
python test.py | wc -l
58
```

Why is that, I can't understand why 58 specifically? I would have thought it would return just 1 and that is all that is within the output variable?

p.s. I know there are python libraries that can be used to get the system time / date, but this is more about me learning python statements and subprocess.

EDIT: I should add, even without the 'wc -l' it still returns 58 full returns from the date command.

EDIT: If i replace 'date' with 'ls' it runs the 'ls' command twice to its entirety.

EDIT: Another example, if I use 'whoami' it returns my username seven times?

Comment: Try running `python test.py` alone :P. It's not running 58 times. Output is just a string of 58 characters, and your for loop prints the output once for each of those characters.

Comment: You might want to distinguish `print`ing from `return`ing. You can only `return` from a function (and, thus, a loop inside a function) once per function call.

Comment: `for x in output: print output` => "For each character in output, print output"

Comment: Without 'wc -l' it still returns 58 instances of the date 'Thu 16 Jul 17:19:43 BST 2015'

Comment: `for x in output: print output` -> `print output`?

Comment: Use `proc.stdout.readline()` and `print(output)` (not in a loop).

Comment: @luke, how are you counting the 58 instances of the date?

Comment: It makes sense now, its iterating through 'x'

Comment: Interesting that it's 58, not 29. What do you get if you change it to `print x, output`?

Answer (score 6):

`output` is a string (or in Python 3 it's a bytestring). Iterating over a string/bytestring will iterate over the individual characters. Try `print x` to see what is actually being iterated over.

You are printing all of `output` once for each character in `output`. The string ends in `'\n'` so you get two lines of output for each of the 29 characters in the string. That's where 58 comes from.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('date', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output = proc.stdout.read()
>>> for x in output:
...         print output
... 
Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

Thu Jul 16 16:28:33 BST 2015

>>>
```

Comment: Nope, it adds a full new date line 58 times 'Thu 16 Jul 17:19:43 BST 2015'

Comment: No, it only prints the date 29 times interleaved with 29 blank lines. Try it without the `wc -l`.

Comment: As Duncan explained, the flow is for 'T' in 'Thu 16 Jul 17:19:43 BST 2015,print 'Thu 16 Jul 17:19:43 BST 2015, for 'h' in 'Thu 16 Jul 17:19:43 BST 2015, print 'Thu 16 Jul 17:19:43 BST 2015 and so on. You are printing output and not x, so you are getting the whole date multiple times.

Comment: Makes sense now. I guess I need to rethink how I do this.